# How to bind an integer to a WPF template

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I can't bind an integer variable to the template.

My C# code looks like below:

```
    class Task
{
    public string name;
    public string desc;
    public int pr;

    public string TaskName
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return desc; }
        set { desc = value; }
    }

    public int Priority
    {
        get { return pr; }
        set { pr = value; }
    }

    public Task(string name, string description, int pr)
    {
        this.TaskName = name;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Priority = pr;
    }
}
```

and the XAML code is

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="myTaskTemplate">
        <Border Name="border" BorderBrush="DarkSlateBlue" BorderThickness="2" 
  CornerRadius="2" Padding="5" Margin="5">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Padding="0,0,5,0" Text="Task Name:"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=TaskName}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Padding="0,0,5,0" Text="Description:"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Padding="0,0,5,0" Text="Priority:"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Priority}"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
```

There is always "0" for the Priority column now. The other binding variables are displayed correctly, but they are strings.

Comment: How do you create your Task? Are you sure that `Priority` doesn't 0? Because your code looks OK it should work.

Comment: also, is Priority value changed after initializing in ctor?

Comment: `list.Add(new Task("test", "testowe zadanie", 1));`

Comment: Put a debug on the Priority get and I suspect it has a value of 0.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, check the output window when creating a task and see if it says anything. This is where they usually tell you if a binding didnt work. If not then the binding is working so you probably are changing the value somewhere (before loading).

Answer (score 1):

Ussualy the ViewModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged in order to propagate changes in  properties to the view.

This being said, your class should look like this:

```
class Task : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string name;
    public string desc;
    public int pr;

    public string TaskName
    {
        get { return name; }
        set 
        { 
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TaskName"); 
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get { return desc; }
        set 
        { 
            desc = value; 
            OnPropertyChanged("Description"); 
        }
    }

    public int Priority
    {
        get { return pr; }
        set 
        {
            pr = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Priority"); 
        }
    }

    public Task(string name, string description, int pr)
    {
        this.TaskName = name;
        this.Description = description;
        this.Priority = pr;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string pName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He may actually need to do this, but this is not really the point in this question. He's setting the property in the constructor so it should be set to one before the view gets the values from the property.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't do any thing wrong, But check your code because the priority is overwritten in some where else the clue of that is your other binding works fine, don't forget to change your binding in all the property to be like ControlProperty="{Binding ClassProperty,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"

Comment: if he wants to do this he also needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire the OnPropertyChanged event in the properties